# search value from xml on the basis of some tag id

Tags: javascript, xml, search

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ChannelListResp>
    <counttotal>8</counttotal>
    <channellist>
        <channel>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Channel 1</name>
        </channel>
        <channel>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Channel 2</name>
        </channel>
        <channel>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>Channel 3</name>
        </channel>
        <channel>
            <id>4</id>
            <name>Channel 4</name>
        </channel>
        <channel>
            <id>5</id>
            <name>Life 5</name>
        </channel>
    </channellist>
</ChannelListResp>
```

How would i get name of channel on the basis of id using javascript. I have this xml returned as an object.

For example if i pass 4 then it should return Channel 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseXML(){
    try{
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOC");
    }catch(e){
        try{
            var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
        }catch(e){ return;}
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}

var xmlDoc = parseXML();
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load("foo.xml");
var channellist = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("channel");
```

now you can get the channel you need,for example:

```
var channel_3 = channellist[2];
```

Comment: I guess you can not use this in browsers other than IE

Answer (score 0):

Try converting xml to json object & then you can use jquery grep() function to get what u need.